# Detect collision between sprite and bitmap in Phaser

Tags: javascript, bitmap, collision-detection, collision, phaser-framework

How to detect collision between sprite and shape created by bitmap?

In example I have sprite:

```
this.player = this.add.sprite(0, 0, 'player')
this.player.anchor.setTo(0.5)
this.player.scale.setTo(0.1)
```

And bitmap: ﻿

```
this.bmd = this.game.add.bitmapData(2000, 2000)
this.bmd.addToWorld()
```

And then I draw shape using bmd object:

```
this.bmd.rect(px, py + 15, 5, 500, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)')
```

Then I call this method:

```
this.bmd.update()
```

It looks more or less like in 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE6Xx.png).
Yellow ball is my sprite.
White curved line is my shape created from bitmapdata.
And I want detect collision between yellow object and white line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it - these examples are very helpful http://jsfiddle.net/4yh8ee1f/46/ and https://phaser.io/examples/v2/sprites/sprite-from-bitmapdata

```
var bmd = game.add.bitmapData(128,128);

bmd.ctx.beginPath();
bmd.ctx.rect(0,0,128,128);
bmd.ctx.fillStyle = '#ff0000';
bmd.ctx.fill();

var sprite = game.add.sprite(200, 200, bmd);
```

When I have 2 sprites (player and bitmap) collision detection is very simple.